# Program to find vowels and consonants in a sentence

Tags: java

So I'm writing code to count the no. of vowels and consonants in a sentence. But the output for the both cases is 0.

I'm using `removeAll();` to remove the whitespaces or tabs or commas or fullstops, etc. I'm not able to find anything wrong with my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class VowelsConsonantsSentence 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input The Sentence : ");
        String in = sc.nextLine();
        in = in.toLowerCase();
        in = in.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        in = in.replaceAll(".","");
        in = in.replaceAll(",","");
        int vCount=0, count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++)
        {
            char x = in.charAt(i);
            switch(x)
            {
                case 'a' :
                case 'e' :
                case 'i' :
                case 'o' :
                case 'u' : vCount++;
                break;
                default : count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nNo. of vowels : "+vCount);
        System.out.println("\nNo. of consonants : "+count);
    }
}
```

Both the variable `count` and `vCount` evaluate to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replaceAll` takes regex as input so `"."` removes all characters.

You can remove all `replaceAll` with `in = in.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+","");` and it should work.

Comment: @meisner97 Be sure to mark the answer as accepted if it helped by clicking the green tick next to the answer. Also for the future, if you'd use a debugger or simply print the value after every replace, you could've easily pinned down the statement that caused the problem. And with that, you possibly even could've solved it yourself.

Comment: @Jaydip It doesn't works it shows the output as 0 for both vowels and consonants

Comment: @meisner97 [It works fine.](https://tio.run/##fVJLb8IwDL73V1i9EFSo9riNcUCcJrFd4DTGpBAMBIJTJS6wTfx2llI2YMB8qfW97EaeyaWsz0bz7VYvMusYZgFIc9Ym7SpJhK4RRVk@NFqBMtJ7eJaa4CuCUHvcs@TwWVo9gkVgRZedpkl/ANJNfHUvLmofCV5BEwhXP4DofnjGRaqp2jiIS8zmnGYhj0X8RFnO0JsidJEYSSE8QHxs2Q2GsGAzzEgJ19zRhOJIsuM0pWw7doWuLf1F2mFmpMKWMSLuv7fqr7L@OUjiWhyfiBmWbZsTN29qoMrmQI@tE4VEB1A/hlCDNOFpGKeTpPorOzxPUWoqHazLJYq@xUIfjSzKrzSrqVhXT9DTmF1U@DeoyAo8XKHwOqWvU/Y6lQdq/yJJ0jgTFTV0KOfn1AjHMjcc7OqSexOdd3/vw5CI3@jFpmDH4RhXaHxxHkm5zz@HdWJUlrwlSVya1ZF3E2222x56vr27/wY)

Comment: As you say. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Ivar What does this `+` sign signifies here. I know it signifies multiple characters/digits but what is its use here in `[^a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: It means 1 or more. `[^a-zA-Z]` means every character except those between A and Z (both uppere and lower case) so here it means it will replace 1 or more of those in a row.

Comment: @Ivar Okay Got It. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works by first removing everything that's not a vowel and taking the length of the remaining string. Then it removes everything that's not a letter to give a letter count. Obviously `consonantCount = letterCount - vowelCount`.

```
String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
s = s.toLowerCase();
int vowelCount = s.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "").length();
int letterCount = s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").length();
int consonantCount = letterCount - vowelCount;
System.out.printf("Vowels: %d\n", vowelCount);
System.out.printf("Consonants: %d\n", consonantCount);
```

Output:

```
Vowels: 11
Consonants: 24
```

Comment: Thanks For The Input